# Encoding type as a var

Tags: c#, encoding, var

```
if (radioButton1.Checked) {
    var Enc = Encoding.Unicode;
}

var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath, (Enc);
```

It doesn't work, any way to make the encoding type a var so I can later p

Comment: `(` count:  3,  `)` count: 2,  try again

Comment: The problem is that your code doesn't work.  You have to fix it in order for it to work.

Comment: Technically there are at least 2 errors. One of them is the round bracket not closed.

Comment: @pst the "right" response is more probably var enc = radioButton1.Checked ? Encoding.Unicode : Encoding.UTF8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't using `var` - it's that you've declared the variable inside a block, and then you're trying to use it *outside* the block.

Here's an alternative:

```
var encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // Default to UTF-8

if (useUtf16RadioButton.Checked)
{
    encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
}
var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath, encoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you must assign a value when you declare a variable with var so the type can be inferred (also you did specify `Enc` only within the scope of the if condition so it couldn't be used afterwards):

```
var Enc = Encoding.UTF8; //default
if (radioButton1.Checked) {
    Enc = Encoding.Unicode;
}

var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Enc);
```